# Map vs. Class Properties advice

Tags: java, properties

I'm writing a program with a bunch of classes that will be serialized to save in a database and to be sent through a network.

To make things easier for accessing the class properties via command line interface, I'm considering storing the properties in a Map class, instead of giving each property it's own variable.

Basically, instead of using something like this:

```
String id = account.getUserId();
```

I would do this

```
String id = account.properties.get("userId");
```

Is this an advisable way to do things?

Comment: I would suggest doing as above, but use enum's rather than strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a pretty sensible model. It's sometimes called the "[prototype object model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)" and is very similar to how you would work in JavaScript where every object is effectively a Map. This in turn has led to the very popular JSON serialisation format.

Nice features:

- You don't have to worry about messy inheritance heirarchies - you can just alter the properties at will.
- You can create a new object just by copying from another object (the prototype)
- Code to manipulate the data can do so in a uniform way, without having to explicitly name all the variables.
- It's more "dynamic" compared to a static class definition - it's easy to extend and modify your objects

Potential risks / downsides:

- You need to keep track of your property names if you use Strings - the compiler won't do it for you! This issue can be alleviated by using Enums as keys, but then you lose some flexibility...
- You don't get the benefits of static type checking, so you may find that you need to write more JUnit tests as a result to ensure things are working properly
- There is a slight performance overhead (though probably not enough to worry about, as map lookups are very fast)

I actually wrote an entire game in the 90s using a variant og this object model ([Tyrant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tyrant/)) and it worked very well.

Rather than having a Map object exposed however, you may want to consider encapsulating this functionality so that you can use an accessor method on the object itself, e.g.

```
String id = account.getProperty("userId");
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel better about moving forward with this.

Answer (score 2):

How I prefer to do this is often like this:

```
enum StringPropertyType {
   USERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
}

interface StringAttributes {
    String get(StringPropertyType s);
    void put(StringPropertyType s, String value);
}

class MapBasedStringAttributes implements StringAttributes {
    Map<StringPropertyType, String> map = new HashMap<~>();
    String get(StringPropertyType s) { return map.get(s); }
    void put(StringPropertyType s, String value) { map.put(s,value); }
}
```

this gives you compile-time safety, refactoring, etc.

you could also use the stringPropertyType.name() to get the string representation of the enum value and use

```
Map<String,String>
```

instead..

Comment: Thanks much! I can only give one answer a green check, but you'd get one too if I could do more.

Comment: no worries, I'm not in it for the points.... if you have any more questions I'll be glad to elaborate